# Nexus can't update new version from maven center repository

Tags: maven, nexus

When i create a maven prject which depend smtp 1.5.0, during updating denpendencies,
[image]

but the version exsit in center repo,
[image]

below is center repository config in my nexus(v2.2-01), 
[image]

after do the operate (expire cache, repair index,update index)below,
[image]

Updating the project dependency again, but no use.

i check the storage browser,index browser, remote browser,
[image] 
[image]
[image]

it seems my nexus has not get the index from center, and also has not get the smtp jar.

so what happened to my nexus?

Comment: The last screenshot `Browse Remote` and the entries `http:search.maven.org` look wrong. The remote storage location must be `http://central.maven.org/maven2/`. Furthermore i would recommend to update your nexus installation cause 2.2 is really old. Up-to-date is 2.8.X

Comment: The real reason is that someone change the httpclient jar depended by nexus, and throw out class cast exception. thank you all the same!